# What is the purpose of "workflow:rules" in Gitlab-ci pipelines?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am a bit confused between Gitlab CI pipeline `workflow:rules` and `job:rules`

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'
```

and

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: image
  script:
    - echo "Hello world!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
```

What happens if both of them were used in the same GitLab-ci YAML file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With `worfklow` you configure when a pipeline is [created](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow) while with `rules` you configure when a job is [created](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

So in your example pipelines are created for pushes but cannot be scheduled while your `test` job will only run when scheduled.

But as workflow rules take precedence over job rules, no pipeline will be created in your example as your rules for workflow and job are mutually exclusive.